# How to handle tuples and single tokens differently in C++ preprocessing?

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor

I want to define a `INITIALIZE(...)` that achieves the following

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string a;
    bool b;
    char c;
    double d;
    INITIALIZE(a, (b, true), (c, '$'), d);
};
```

gets expanded to

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string a;
    bool b;
    char c;
    double d;

    void init() {
        a = get_value<std::string>();  // use return value of get_value function
        b = true;                      // use init value from the macro
        c = '$';                       // use init value from the macro
        d = get_value<double>();       // use return value of get_value function
    }
};
```

Are these achievable with the help of `Boost_PP` macros?

`T get_value<T>()` is defined in a library.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @n.'pronouns'm. I have update the question with a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost doable, you need an extra pair of parens around things initialized by default.

```
 #define INIT_1(x) x = get_value<decltype(x)>();
 #define INIT_2(x, y) x = y;
 #define INIT_ONE(...) BOOST_PP_CAT(INIT_, \
                           BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
 #define INIT_ONE_X(r, data, elem) INIT_ONE elem
 #define INITIALIZE(...) void init () { BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( \
                           INIT_ONE_X, x, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) }
```

Now `INITIALIZE((a), (b, 'a'), (c))` expands to

```
void init () { a = get_value<decltype(a)>(); b = 'a'; c = get_value<decltype(c)>(); }
```

EDIT: As suggested by @Quentin, you can get rid of extra parentheses by using a macro similar to [this](https://gitlab.com/D-z/glk/-/raw/master/include/glk/pp/ensureParens.h). Necessary changes are

```
#define INIT_ONE_XX(elem)  INIT_ONE elem
#define INIT_ONE_X(r, data, elem) INIT_ONE_XX(ENSURE_PARENS(elem))

#define ENSURE_PARENS(...) \
  BOOST_PP_REMOVE_PARENS( \
          BOOST_PP_IF( \
              BOOST_PP_IS_BEGIN_PARENS(__VA_ARGS__), \
              (__VA_ARGS__), \
              ((__VA_ARGS__)) \
              ) \
                                                                          )
```

Then `INITIALIZE(a, (b, 'a'), c)` also works.

Edit: a better, less obstructive syntax could be possible, depending on what exact C++ construct we generate. See http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/ for inspiration.

Comment: You can make parentheses optional by [conditionally adding them back before further processing](https://gitlab.com/D-z/glk/-/raw/master/include/glk/pp/ensureParens.h).

Comment: @Quentin nice, I didn't know it's possible.